# How to insert part of a string into an int?

Tags: java, android, string, int

I have the `String = "08/21/2018"`.

How can I get only `"08"` from this line and insert this value into a `int`?

FInal result must be `int month = 01`.

Comment: You can use _split_ or _subString_.

Comment: use subString or regex or if its date parse DD only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to split string and need to get **0 index value** and parse that in an **integer** value.As shown in below code.

```
    String date = "08/21/2018";
    String [] splitDate = date.split("/");
    int month = Integer.valueOf(splitDate[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  String date= "08/21/2018";
            String[] arr=date.split(Pattern.quote("/"));
            int month = Integer.parseInt(arr[0]);
            int day = Integer.parseInt(arr[1]);
            int year = Integer.parseInt(arr[2]);
```

Comment: He's using m/d/y so it should be `int day = Integer.parseInt(arr[1]); int month = Integer.parseInt(arr[0]);`

Comment: right, sorry i didn't notice that, Thank you